# Como mais de um servidor envia informações para um único site?

Tags: servidor, google, youtube

De maneira simples, paço esse exemplo:

Como é que por exemplo; o YouTube, que tem muitos servidores no mundo todo, consegue por exemplo enviar para apenas um único site? Porque no meu ver um servidor não dá para tantas pessoas.
Servidor no meu entender é um computador. Mas o Youtube utiliza vários.
Então quero saber como é que eles não ficam com erros, ou seja, trabalham juntos e enviam resposta para todo mundo através de um site.

Comment: Isso é resolvido antes mesmo de chegar ao servidor, geralmente na rede e claro só vai servir o que tiver disponivel, geralmente também existindo espelhamentos e resolvendo via DNS qual deve apontar para qual. É algo mais da área de redes do que de WEB mesmo, não domino muito o assunto.

Comment: Pesquise por *gateway*, *proxie* reverso ou *load balance* que entenderá melhor um pouco da infraestrutura.